# So where do people go with the off topic questions?

Tags: discussion

It's a follow on from another post here.

Let's examine this:

[How can I efficiently get all employees to read and sign-off on a policy?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9139/how-do-i-get-an-employee-to-read-and-sign-off-a-policy)

Now according to the FAQ, this should be closed.

> How do I learn to be a..." / "How do I perform the job of a ..."
>
> Questions should be about problems you are encountering or have
>   encountered in the workplace, and not the learning/applying of
>   specific job functions.

So I am curious in this instance, where would that person post to find the answer to that question?

Comment: to find if there's a place for particular kind OT questions, try asking in [meta-tag:chat] or search / ask at [site-rec tag at MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-rec)

Comment: I don't think that question is off-topic. It may be asking about a job function, however that job function is part of an HR department's job, which I believe makes it on-topic. That line in the FAQ was originally put there because people were asking about other job functions, such as how to accomplish an IT-specific job function.

Answer (score 2):

Off topic means only one thing; it's not on topic here. It's not a promise that it's on topic elsewhere, either on Stack Exchange or anywhere else on the internet. There's no obligation for anyone to provide an alternate place for any or all off topic questions; they simply don't belong.

Likewise, whether something's on topic elsewhere is largely irrelevant to whether it's off topic here. There's some border cases where questions are better served elsewhere but they're kinda okay here, but for the most part just because it's on topic over at Y.SE doesn't mean it's off topic on X.SE and vice versa.

---

<sub>I'm not saying this example was entirely off topic and I voted to reopen it after some good edits, but that doesn't change anything else here. It's either on topic or it's not.</sub>